# WPF: Why is my Thread only updating some values

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

First of all, I don't have a general problem with my thread not updating values, it's just one value.

I created a clock that's made of Progress bars. The "engine" behind the clock is a second thread:

```
Thread clock = new Thread(UpdateRelative);

clock.IsBackground = true;
clock.Start();
```

Before I come to the `UpdateRelative()`-Method, this is my Clock in Xaml:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.DataContext>
        <vm:TimerVM/>
    </Grid.DataContext>
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Margin="10,10,10,10">
        <Border BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="1">
            <Label Content="Progress Bar Timer" FontFamily="Bold" FontSize="45" HorizontalAlignment="Center" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Margin="0,0,0,20"/>
        </Border>
        <StackPanel>
            <Label Content="Seconds in this Minute:"/>
            <Grid Width="400" Height="25">
                <ProgressBar Value="{Binding SecondsInMinute}" />
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <Run Text="{Binding SecondsInMinute, StringFormat=N0}"/><Run Text="%"/>
                </TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel>
            <Label Content="Minutes in this hour:"/>
            <Grid Width="400" Height="25">
                <ProgressBar Value="{Binding MinutesInHour}" />
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <Run Text="{Binding MinutesInHour, StringFormat=N0}"/><Run Text="%"/>
                </TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel>
            <Label Content="Hours in this day:"/>
            <Grid Width="400" Height="25">
                <ProgressBar Value="{Binding HoursInDay}" />
                <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <Run Text="{Binding HoursInDay, StringFormat=N0}"/><Run Text="%"/>
                </TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Margin="0,50,0,0">
            <Label Content="Time until timer finished:"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <Grid Width="400" Height="25">
            <ProgressBar Value="{Binding TimerInPercent}" />
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <Run Text="{Binding TimerInPercent, StringFormat=N0}"/><Run Text="%"/>
            </TextBlock>
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

In the program it looks like this:

[image]

Now to the method: This gets executed by my second thread:

```
private void UpdateRelative()
{
    bool x = false;
    while (true)
    {
        DateTime time = DateTime.Now;

        SecondsInMinute = time.Second / 0.6;
        MinutesInHour = time.Minute / 0.6;
        HoursInDay = time.Hour / 0.24;

        if (timerReady)
        {
            if (!x)
            {
                //TimerEnd is the current time plus 2 minutes
                TimerEnd = new DateTime(TimerYear, TimerMonth, TimerDay, TimerHour, TimerMin, TimerSec);

                TimerInPercent = 0;
                x = true;
                Start = DateTime.Now;
            }

            DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
            DateTime end = TimerEnd;

            var endTimeSpan = now - Start;

            TimeSpan entireTime = end - Start;

            TimerInPercent = (100 / entireTime.TotalSeconds) * endTimeSpan.TotalSeconds;
        }

        Thread.Sleep(timeout);
    }
}
```

The general problem is the `TimerInPercent`. I placed it in an if-statement, cause it should only start to update, after I pressed a button. At the Moment the "end time" for the timer is set 2 minutes after starting the program. While every value itself gets updated (`SecondsInMinute`, `MinutesInHour`, `HoursInDay` and `TimerInPercent`), only the first three also get updated in the GUI.

This is the TimerInPercent:

```
public double TimerInPercent
{
    get => _timerInPercent;
    set
    {
        _timerInPercent = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

For example, I start the program at 8:30. The Timer is now set to 8:32. Now I press the "OK"-Button. While debugging, I can see that the value `TimerInPercent` is changing its value. But despite the other values, this value doesn't get updated in the GUI.

When I remove the if-statement and update the value from beginning, it updates in the GUI.

My question is: Why isn't the thread updating the value in the GUI, if the value isn't updated from the beginning, but later (after I pressed a button)

Comment: Can you share the `TimerInPercent` property implementation?

Comment: I agree with @Eldar, it's probably in your setter of TimerInPercent. You should make sure that TimerInPercent notifies that the property has changed. Also, when you make a typo there, it will not raise an error, so check again for typos in case you pass the member name "TimerInPercent" hard coded.

Comment: Did you wrap UI related code into `Dispatcher`?

Comment: As a general note, you shoud not be using threads explicitly. Either use async/await, or (better here) a DispatcherTimer.